# What is a Gelfand-Tsetlin subalgebra?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, lie-algebras

For context on general Gelfand-Tsetlin theory, see for instance this MO [post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/315268/is-there-an-accessible-exposition-of-gelfand-tsetlin-theory).

Let's work over $\mathbb{C}$. Fix $n>0$. There is a natural chain of embeddings of the general linear Lie algebras $\mathfrak{gl}_1 \subset \mathfrak{gl}_2 \subset \ldots \subset \mathfrak{gl}_n$.

Calling $U_i=U(\mathfrak{gl}_i)$, this induces a chain of embeddings $U_1 \subset \ldots \subset U_n$. Call $Z_m$ the center of $U_m$.

It is a polynomial algebra in $m$ indeterminates $c_{mk}=\sum_{(i_1,\ldots,i_k) \in \{1, \ldots, m \}^k} e_{i_1 i_2} e_{i_2 i_3} \ldots e_{i_k i_i}$, for $k=1,\ldots,m$, and where $e_{ij}$ are the matrix units.

The subalgebra of $U_n$ generated by $\bigcup_{k=1}^n Z_k$ is a commutative subalgebra called the Gelfand-Tsetlin subalgebra and denoted by $Z$.

$Z$ has some remarkable properties:

i) $Z$ is a polynomial algebra in $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ indeterminates.

ii) it is maximal commutative subalgebra of $U(\mathfrak{gl}_n)$ (with respect to inclusion). This has result has been folklore for decades, but the first proof was given by Ovsienko in 2002.

iii) it is a commutative subalgebra of maximal possible transcendence degree. Recent work of Yakimova show that being maximal commutative and having maximal transcendence degree are not the same thing in general enveloping algebras.

iv) each vector in the [Gelfand-Tsetlin basis](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0211289) of irreducible $\mathfrak{gl}_n$-modules is an eigenvector for $Z$.

v) $U(\mathfrak{gl}_n)$ is a free $Z$-module (Futorny, Ovsienko 2005).

The classifical reference for this subject is Zhebolenko's 'Compact Lie groups and their representations'.

Mazorchuk in his paper '*On Gelfand-Zetlin modules over orthogonal Lie algebras*' introduced  a concept of Gelfand-Tsetlin subalgebra for the enveloping algebra of orthogonal Lie algebras. It satisfies the same properties ii), iii), iv) above.

The idea of a Gelfand-Tsetlin subalgebra has big consequence for representation theory. In case of $U(\mathfrak{gl}_n)$ this leads to the theory of [Gelfandt-Tsetlin modules](https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/10.1142/9789813272880_0098), introduced by Drozd, Futorny and Ovsienko. It is the largest category of $\mathfrak{gl}_n$ modules (much bigger than category $\mathcal{O}$) where the problem of classifying all irreducible objects has been carried out. The very same idea was used by Okunkov and Vershik in their famous paper '*A new approach to representation theory of symmetric groups*', where a certain maximal commutative subalgebra of $\mathbb{C}S_n$, generated by the Jucys-Murphy elements play the central role.

Finally, a completely abstract framework for the theory of Gelfand-Tsetlin subalgebras for general associative algebras was developed by Futorny and Ovsienko in two papers. '*Galois orders in skew monoid rings*' and '*Fiber of characters of Gelfand-Tsetlin theories*'. In this setting, for instance, the polynomial subalgebra $\mathbb{C}[\partial_1 x_1, \ldots, \partial_n x_n]$ of the rank $n$ Weyl algebra $A_n$ is a Gelfand-Tsetlin subalgebra.

My question, however, is restricted to the case of enveloping algebras o semisimple Lie algebras:

Question 1: Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a simple Lie algebra of type $B$, $C$ or $D$. What should be a Gelfand-Tsetlin subalgebra for $U(\mathfrak{g})$?

Recently, Rybnikov and Zavanlin, in '
Gelfand–Tsetlin Degeneration of Shift of Argument Subalgebras in Types B, C and D' constructed some commutative subalgebras of $U(\mathfrak{g})$ in these cases, but it is not clear to me if they satisfy all necessary conditions to be called a Gelfand-Tsetlin subalgera (the nature of these necessary conditions is not precise, and the point of this question is to make them as precise as possible). In particular, it is unkown if Rybnikov and Zavaling subalgebras are the same as Mazorchuk's in case of orthogonal Lie algebras; in the paper the authors produce combinatorial basis for the irreducible $\mathfrak{g}$ modules, but their relation with the Gelfand-Tsetlin bases considered by Molev is unknown.

My second question arises from a more general one I learned from Mazorchuk:

Question 2: Can there be a notion of Gelfand-Tsetlin subalgebra of $U(\mathfrak{g})$ when $\mathfrak{g}$ when $\mathfrak{g}$ is a simple Lie algebra of types E, F or G?

Comment: If you take the perspective that Gelfand-Tsetlin algebras arise from multiplicity-free chains of subgroups, it is known that the only chains of multiplicity-free branching rules for connected reductive groups are formed by $GL_*$ and $SO_*$ (Krämer, "Multiplicity Free Subgroups of Compact Connected Lie Groups"). On the other hand, I recommend the paper "A remark on the Gelfand-Tsetlin patterns for symplectic groups" by Kirillov for some intriguing speculations.

Comment: @JoshuaMundinger thank you very much. I was not aware of Kirillov's paper.